# How to highlight an item from flatlist and show delete option to delete that item from the list on long press of that item?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to highlight an item from the flatlist on long press of that item and show delete option to delete that item from the list.

```
    renderFlatlist = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.flatListContainer}>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.flatListStyle}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={this.state.fetchProjectDetail}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    console.log("_renderItem", item.id);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
        onLongPress={this._handleLongPress(item)}
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateProject", {
            database: this.props.navigation.state.params.database,
            id: item.id,
            from: "edit"
          });
        }}
      >
        <Text>Project Name: {item.project_name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  _handleLongPress = item => {
    Alert.alert("LongPress");
  };
```

I have done this much, but when I render the list that alert keeps popping up without long press of that item from the list. And how do I highlight the item on long press and display a delete option to delete the item from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the handler right away, but it needs to be a callback, i.e. `() => this._handleLongPress(item)`. From there you can set whatever state you need to highlight that row.

I suggest using an auxiliary data structure to track which items have been long pressed. Here's an example where I use a map to store the item id of selected items and apply a highlighting style. If you haven't the need for multiple selected you could just save the selected id by itself.

The trick here is to use react's FlatList `extraData` prop as a tigger to re-render the list as the data prop is unchanged (for good reason, you shouldn't mutate your data source inside components).

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-7ds3r?fontsize=14)

Comment: const selected = { ...this.state.selected } , here what will be the value of selected and how ?

Comment: If you are referring to line 88, `this.state.selected` is a map of selected items [id => boolean].  On this line the object is spread into a new local variable (also called `selected`). You can then toggle (i.e. mutate) this object and not affect component state.  We used the local variable name `selected` so we could shorten the code a bit when setting new state (remember, react `setState` merges in new updates, and if no key is used then the variable's name is used *as* the key.